# submitting comments posts an ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I'm trying to get my comments posted to a particular post, but I'm getting a Missing Template comments/comment. I looked up some possible reasons, and I think it has to do with my rendering of comment but I don't know how to fix it.

In my CommentsController I have the render

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
        render 'comment'
    end
```

In view/comments it's there too

```
<% @comments.each |do| comment %>
    <div class="media">
        <div class"media-body"
            <h4 class="media-heading">
            <ul>
                <li><% render comment %></li>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I also include it here in view/posts/show becaues I want the comments to create a list with each in-comming post.

```
<h1><%= markdown @post.title %></h1>

<div class="row"> <!-- what others are there besides row? -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p><%= markdown @post.body %></p>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
        <%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @post.comments.new } %>
        <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {comment: @comment} %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I naming the rendering incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part of your question, the `render "comment"` statement actually looks for the view file associated to the `comment` action (which turns out, you did not define in your controller). The correct way would be to

1. create the file `app/views/comments/comment.html`
2. Change your code in the controller into the following

   def create
     # your logic here
     render "comments/comment"
     # rails know that you are looking for a file rather than a view associated to a certain action with the backslash
   end

About the second part of your question (I might misunderstand your question), you are asking why the following does not work?

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
```

This is because in `render :partial => "controller/partial"`, rails will look for the file `app/views/controller/_partial.html.erb` instead of what is typed.

In your situation, what might be appropriate is to create a partial `comments/_comments.html.erb` and render that partial from both your posts#show action and comments#create action.

Comment: I have this file created so I think I can say

`render 'comments/_comment'` in my CommentsController

`<%= render partial: 'comments/_form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @post.comments.new } %>`  and

`<%= render partial: 'comments/_comment', locals: {comment: @comment} %>` in my view/posts/show.html.erb

correct?